# Ownable Minimal Proxy (EIP-1167)

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, eip-1167

I'm trying to create a clone from a contract that has some privileged functions and inherits from `Ownable`.
I realized that after cloning the `owner` variable is zeroed, so any privileged function, such as `transferOwnership`, won't run.

I noticed that Ownable has a internal function `_transferOwnership` that is not protected by `onlyOwner` modifier. I thought about calling it in my initializer function.

I just want to confirm that this is the right way to do it or it has a more recommended way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to your initializer to set `owner` on your implementation. When deploying new contracts from your factory, this variable will be used to set `owner`.

Or I can recommend you to use `OwnableUpgradeable` that includes initializers instead of constructors, `initializable` functions can be called only once.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol

Comment: `OwnableUpgradeable` won't help here: it only sets the owner to `msg.sender` which happens to be the factory.